# HTML5 - how to stop audio when another audio tag starts playing?

Tags: javascript, html, function, audio, playback

I have this javascript function:

```
var currentPlayer;
function EvalSound(soundobj) {
    var thissound = document.getElementById(soundobj);
    if (currentPlayer && currentPlayer != thissound) {
        currentPlayer.pause(); 
    }
    if (thissound.paused) {
        thissound.play();
    } else {
        thissound.pause();
    }
    thissound.currentTime = 0;
    currentPlayer = thissound;
}
```

And this html5 audio player repeating in a loop inside a Gridview widget in Yii2 (it creates many players each of them with a different song):

```
'value'=> function ($data){                      
    return "<audio controls>
            <source src='" . $data->ficheiro . "' type='audio/mp3' />
            </audio>";
},
```

The problem is when I have an audio tag playing and click on the play button of another it doesn't stop the previous playing audio tag and starts the new one. Both audio tags play at the same time. I'm trying to adapt the javascript function but it doesn´t work.

I also tried declaring `var thisound = $('audio');`

It also does not work.

Do I need to put an ID in the audio tag?
Do I need to associate an `onClick='EvalSound'` event to the audio tag?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, here is how I solved it:

The `addEventListener` grabs the audio beginning to play and the `for` loop pauses all other audio tags.

```
document.addEventListener('play', function(e) {
    var audios = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');

    for (var i = 0, len = audios.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (audios[i] != e.target) {
            audios[i].pause();
        }
    }
}, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a unique way of identifying the `<audio>` tags. And using a generic `$("audio")` seelctor makes the issue worse. Use `id` for all the tags and make it work that way.

Comment: Many thanks. Right know i'm away of the code, but i will try that later.

Comment: Ok. I inserted an onClick='EvalSound' event and an ID='soundobj' into the <audio> tag. It didn´t work :(

Comment: Did you insert the same ID for all the audio tracks?

Comment: Yes. Becauae it is inside a gridview that loops the audio tag and inserts a music stored in database.

Comment: Hey, IDs must be unique. Basic thumb rule. What's that which is generating the grid?

Comment: The gridview loops for each music stored in db and loads an audio tag for each one. If i upload, lets say, 50 songs, the grid will show 50 audio players, one for each if of the 50 song files.

Comment: Is it backend programming logic?

Comment: When i press play in a player the one currently playing should stop and let the new one start playing.

Comment: No. Its in frontend, the gridview is in php with embed html5 audio tag.